# In xamarin.forms I want to know how many seconds a button is tapped before taking action

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In xamarin.forms I want to have a button that will only works if is pressed by 5 seconds
How can I detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no **OnTouchDown/OnTouchUp**-like events available in Xamarin.Forms.

The `Clicked` event and the `TapGestureRecognizer` occur after the touch is complete (ie. press is released).

But you can create a custom control subclassing `Button`, with the following properties:

```cs
public event EventHandler PressStarted;
public event EventHandler PressEnded;
```

And the following public methods:

```cs
public void OnPressStarted()
     {
         if (PressStarted != null)
         {
             PressStarted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
     }

     public void OnPressEnded()
     {
         if (PressEnded != null)
         {
             PressEnded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
         }
     }
```

Then create a renderer per platform to be able to count the time that has pressed the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own button with using Mr.Gesture plugin (paid plugin).
It has OnTouchDown/OnTouchUp event.